# To remove UIGestureRecognizer or not to remove

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app made in Swift that uses gesture recognizers and has multiple scenes. Scenes include a menu, instruction page, gamescene, and gameover screen. If I have a GameScene that initializes swipe gestures, but doesn't remove them, when I lose and go to the GameOver scene, hit replay, and come back to the GameScene, does this create problems? In other words, if I don't remove the gesturerecognizers from the view before switching to another, will this eventually bug my program out after a while?

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.replayButton {
            //interstitialAdChecker()
            var scene = InstructionScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a gesture to a view on a scene, it applies only to that view and doesn't affect other views in other scenes that you might transition to. Don't worry about removing the gestures from scenes from which you have transitioned away. Just make sure the gesture creation is linked to the loading of the view (e.g., `viewDidLoad` or in IB) and not merely the appearance of the view (e.g., `viewDidAppear`).

The only thing that would be problematic (and this is unrelated to your gestures question) would be if you transition from scene A to scene B, but then transition again from B to another copy of A. As long as you're popping/dismissing/unwinding to get from B back to the original instance of A, then you're fine. But if you have some circular pattern of present/push segues, then you can run into memory issues.

Comment: Interesting, I have my scene transitions set up for if the user taps the "retry" button. Does this create said circular pattern and make a copy of the PlayScene or am I ok in the way scene transitioning is handled. Code is in edit above

Comment: @riverhawk Welcome to StackOverflow! :) Please put your code in your question, not as an edit to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Lol sorry, knew I miss clicked!